# Add SVG on the left of the footer using only CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

French speaker sorry for bad syntax or misspelled words

Hi, my Uni asked an odd question in an assignment. They asked to add a SVG on the left of the footer using only CSS (the svg file is not in the html I have to had it in the css file). I tried using `footer::before` in CSS but the svg is too big and if I try to scale it, it just go down outside the footer.

Here is the full code of what I tried:

```css
footer{
  height:50px;
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:rgba(120,120,0,0.6);
}
footer::before {
  content: url(https://img.uefa.com/imgml/uefacom/ucl/2021/logos/logo_dark.svg);
  float: left;
  scale: 0.1;
}
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <strong>Projet TW1 2023 : ma petite compo</strong><br> données issues de <a href="https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/" target="_blan ">uefa.com</a>
</footer>
```

Please note that I can't erase or modify existing rule for `footer{}` I can only add new rules. 
I also tried to add directly the svg code with `content: url("data:image/svg+xml;<svg>...</svg>")` but I could not get this to work

Screenshot of how it is :[image]

And how it should be :[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could get was with using `transform: scale(10%);` and setting `display: inline-block;` and `transform-origin: bottom left;` instead of `float:left;` and `scale: 0.1;`

```css
footer::before {
  content: url(https://img.uefa.com/imgml/uefacom/ucl/2021/logos/logo_dark.svg);
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(10%);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

body {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <strong>Projet TW1 2023 : ma petite compo</strong><br> données issues de <a href="https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/" target="_blan ">uefa.com</a>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to u/tridd3r on rediit for the answer. 
His codepen [Here](https://codepen.io/tristram/pen/xxyxQKX)

The solution was to add the svg as the background of `footer::before` and not a content :

```css
footer{
  height:50px;
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color:rgba(120,120,0,0.6);
}
footer::before {
content: "";
background-image:url(https://img.uefa.com/imgml/uefacom/ucl/2021/logos/logo_dark.svg);
background-size:contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float:left;
display:block;
margin: 1px 15px 5px 5px;
height: 45px;
width:45px;
}
body {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <strong>Projet TW1 2023 : ma petite compo</strong><br> données issues de <a href="https://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/" target="_blan ">uefa.com</a>
</footer>
```